# Laravel 5.1 seems not to be adding config values to S3 Upload

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5.1

I want to use s3 for file storage in my laravel app, but for some weird reason I am getting this error

> S3Exception in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 159:
>       Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.your-region.amazonaws.com/your-bucket/halls/3edf6142206cc1851fc05fa8730e34eb-1.jpeg"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: s3.your-region.amazonaws.com (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

So am thinking that my config values arent reflected in the s3 upload.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured it out. Anytime you make any changes to either the environment file or the config file it is advised to always run `php artisan config:cache` So this clears the old config cache and update with the new values.