# Laravel AWS S3 Upload photo error (Region error?)

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

> Error executing "ListObjects" on
>   "https://s3.your-region.amazonaws.com/your-bucket?prefix=abc%2F1468895496.jpg%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url";
>   AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:
>   s3.your-region.amazonaws.com (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class ProductController extends Controller
{
...
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $imageFileName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
        $filePath = '/abc/' . $imageFileName;
        $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
        return redirect()->action('ProductController@index');
    }
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588066/laravel-5-1-seems-not-to-be-adding-config-values-to-s3-upload/34599133

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you havent set the config in `config/filesystems.php` because the `your-region`, `your-bucket` etc is the default value.

Change at this section and make sure the key, secret, region and bucket are filled up.

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    // s3 part is here
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => 'your-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret',
        'region' => 'ap-southeast-1', // this is the region setting
        'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
    ],

],
```